# final mapping would have more than 1 type error after upgrade

Tags: elasticsearch

After upgrading to 6.7.2 from 6.0.0 we are seeing mapping type error where it is trying to parse 2 types

we do have a type field in our events but looking at the release notes logstash 6.1 stops the type in the event to determine the _type field

The error we see is Rejecting mapping update to [logstash-2019.05.11] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [log4net, doc]"

I am hoping to remove the Log4net type and use the default doc type

Any help is appreciated